# Быстро обрезать ссылки до доменов Memo

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe, delphi-xe7

Как в **Memo1** обрезать ссылки до доменов удалив все **https и http.**

```
https://site1.ru/threads/fdfddd2/
http://site2.ru/threads/fdfddd23434/
https://site3.ru/threads/fdfddd434/
```

Что бы на выходе получилось

```
site1.ru
site2.ru
site3.ru
```

Обрезаю вот так но это очень долго если ссылок **1000 - 3000 ссылок!**

```
// В начале удаляю все до //
    for i:= 0 to Memo1.Lines.Count - 1 do
  Memo1.Lines[i]:= Copy(Memo1.Lines[i], Pos('/', Memo1.Lines[i]) + 2, MaxInt);

// А после удаляю все после
  for i:= 0 to Memo1.Lines.Count - 1 do
  Memo1.Lines[i]:= Copy(Memo1.Lines[i], 1, Pos('/', Memo1.Lines[i])-1);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как обычно уже, не работайте с текстом в VCL компонентах напрямую, это каждый раз вызывает кучу пересчетов. Заберите текст из Мемо, обработайте, положите обратно.

Если нужно именно http обрезать, то как минимум вот так будет в разы быстрее:

```
s := Memo1.Lines.Text;
s := StringReplace(s, 'https:', '', [rfReplaceAll]);
s := StringReplace(s, 'http:', '', [rfReplaceAll]);
Memo1.Lines.Text := s;
```

Для удаления всего после `/` уже придется работать построчно.

---

Вот такой вариант работает почти мгновенно на 4000 строках. Посмотрите что тут делается:

```
procedure TForm1.Memo1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  i: Integer;
  s: string;
begin
  // Достаем текст и делаем авто-замену
  s := Memo1.Lines.Text;
  s := StringReplace(s, 'https://', '', [rfReplaceAll]);
  s := StringReplace(s, 'http://', '', [rfReplaceAll]);
  Memo1.Lines.Text := s;

  // Читаем из списка и складываем в новый список (строку с переносами)
  s := '';
  for i := 0 to Memo1.Lines.Count - 1 do
    s := s + Copy(Memo1.Lines[i], 1, Pos('/', Memo1.Lines[i]) - 1) + sLineBreak;

  Memo1.Lines.Text := s;
end;
```

---

Ну и конечно же, по-хорошему, подготовку (обрезку) данных надо делать ДО помещения в интерфейс.

Comment: Тут еще нужно и удалить все после и оставить только домены.

Comment: Тогда совмещу этих два кода. Спасибо за подсказки!

Comment: @Татьяна продолжая ту же мысль - убираем запись в поля компонента до последнего момента - и все становится супер-быстро.

Comment: Второй ваш код очень быстрый! Спасибо!